Next.JS Getting a 500 Server Error When Trying to Submit my Form with Nodemailer
api/email.ts
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';


export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    const { email, name, message } = await request.json();
    const EMAIL ="myEmail";
    const PASSWORD="myPassword";

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      
        //setting service as 'gmail' is same as providing these setings:
        host: "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
        port: 465,
        service: 'yahoo',

      auth: {
        user: EMAIL,
        pass: PASSWORD,
      },
    });
  
    const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
      from: EMAIL,
      to: EMAIL,
      // cc: email, (uncomment this line if you want to send a copy to the sender)
      subject: `Message from ${name} (${email})`,
      text: message,
    };
  
    const sendMailPromise = () =>
      new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
          if (!err) {
            resolve('Email sent');
          } else {
            reject(err.message);
          }
        });
      });
  
    try {
      await sendMailPromise();
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Email sent' });
    } catch (err) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

utils/send-email.tsx
import { FormData } from '../components/ContactForm';

export function sendEmail(data: FormData) {
  // TODO: send email
  const apiEndpoint = '/api/email';

  fetch(apiEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
      alert(response.message);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert(err);
    });
  console.log(data);
}

Hi everyone, I am new to Next.js and I am getting an error when I send my form, it's giving me a 500 Server error. I am trying to go through yahoo as my mail provider I have created an app password, I can't work out what is going wrong. I try to submit my form and then when I go into the console it gives me an error as follow:-
send-email.tsx:7
POST http://localhost:3000/api/email 500 (Internal Server Error)
The object is there in the console, so I think I have most of the API right. Any help would be much appreciated.

I recommend ensuring that you have explicitly set secure: true, as this port requires an SSL connection from the very beginning of the communication. Also, consider omitting service: 'yahoo' since you're manually specifying the SMTP settings.
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,  // Ensures SSL is used from the start
    auth: {
        user: EMAIL,
        pass: PASSWORD,
    },
});


Hi Niraj I did try that adding the specified secure port and removing the service. I still have the same Internal Server error. Thanks for your input really appreciated.
